# How do I assign values to states once I open my edit form?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-bootstrap, react-apollo

I'm trying to create my first simple CRUD front-end app in React. I have some problems with the edit form.

Whenever I display the edit form with fields filled with values of a chosen record, I need to edit each of the field in order to save it back to the database. If I don't change any of the fields values - including the id of a record - or change only one value, I get the error: 
`[GraphQL error]: Message: could not convert string to float: , Location: undefined, Path: undefined`.
I am aware of the fact, that I can add `Mutation` in `Query` but then I get problems with refetching the updated list of records in the parent component and still get the error message mentioned above.

```
export class EditForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            name: '',
            price: '',
            category: ''
        };
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    };

    updateSome = async () => {
      const {id, name, price, category} = this.state;
      await this.props.editOne({
          variables: {
              id,
              name,
              price,
              category
          },
          refetchQueries: [{ query: ones }]
      })
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Query query={GET_ONE} variables={{one: Number(this.props.id)}}>
        {({ loading, error, data, networkStatus }) => {
            if (loading) return "Loading...";
            if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
            if (networkStatus === 4) return "Refetching!";
            return (
                <div>
                     {data.ones.map(one => (
                       <Form key={one.id}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                        <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>ID</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                name='id'
                                defaultValue={one.id}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="id"
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                        <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                name='name'
                                defaultValue={one.name}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="name"
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>Price</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                name='price'
                                defaultValue={one.price}
                                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                type="number"
                                step={0.01}
                                placeholder="price"
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
                            <Query query={twos}>
                                {({loading, error, data}) => {
                                    if (loading) return <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
                                                <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                                            </Spinner>;
                                    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
                                    return (
                                        <Form.Control name='category'
                                                      defaultValue={one.category.id}
                                                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                                                      as="select"
                                                      placeholder="category"
                                        >
                                            {data.twos.map(two => (
                                        <option key={two.id} value={two.id}>{two.category}</option>
                                                ))}
                                    </Form.Control>
                                    );
                                }}
                            </Query>
                        </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <ButtonToolbar>
                            <Button
                                variant="primary"
                                onClick={() => this.updateSome()}
                            >Update</Button>
                        </ButtonToolbar>
                </Form>
                    ))}
                </div>
            );
        }}
    </Query>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How do I assign initial values of a chosen record to `this.state.id`, `this.state.name` and so on, once the `Component` is displayed? I know how to enter some values to this.state in `constructor` by hand, but I want to pass the values that are displayed in the form fields to `this.state`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably know that using `setState` forces rerender and refetch in `<Query/>` component. Form component (with state and event handling) should be placed inside `<Query/>` to avoid that effect - `getDerivedStateFromProps()` for initial state.

In this case, wthout refactoring it's enough to **conditionally** `setState` in `render`, sth like:

```
            <Query query={GET_ONE} variables={{one: Number(this.props.id)}}>
    {({ loading, error, data, networkStatus }) => {
        if (loading) return "Loading...";
        if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
        if (networkStatus === 4) return "Refetching!";

        // one-time flag, it can be undefined/uninitialized
        if (!this.state.initialized) {
          this.setState( {
            initialized: true, // block this block
            id: data.someField,
            name: data.someField,
            price: data.someField,
            category: data.someField
          })
        }

        return (
```

**GraphQL error** probably refers to a `price` field, convert types in `variables` (within `this.props.editOne` call).

Comment: I quite see your point but I'm not sure how to reach the fields of my form here. Simple ref won't be accepted by React, so it must be something else. I tried to reach data from Query but anything like data.ones.indexOf(0).id doesn't give me the id of a record.

Comment: `data.ones[0].id` ? `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Of course you know that you're using (saving in the state) one set of variables for many records ... overwriting each other? You probably need an array in the state to save values for all records.